# Flex HttpService POST limited to 543 Byte per Form field?

Tags: asp.net, apache-flex, actionscript, post, httpservice

I am getting a FaultEvent when trying to send form fields through HTTPService that contain more than 542 chars.

Initializing the HttpService:

```
httpServ = new HTTPService();
httpServ.method = 'POST';
httpServ.url = ENDPOINT_URL; //http://localhost:3001/ReportError.aspx
httpServ.resultFormat = HTTPService.RESULT_FORMAT_TEXT;
httpServ.contentType = HTTPService.CONTENT_TYPE_FORM;
httpServ.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, OnErrorSent);
httpServ.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, OnFault);
```

Sending the request:

```
var params:Object = {};         
//params["stack"] = e.stackTrace.slice(0, 542); //length 542 = works
//params["stack2"] = e.stackTrace.slice(1, 543); //length 542 = works (just to show that it's not about the content itself)
params["stack3"] = e.stackTrace.slice(0, 543); //length 543 = fails
```

I also seem to be able to create many form fields (with 542 length) so that it's not a limit of the request itself but of the form field:

```
var params:Object = {};         
params["stack"] = e.stackTrace.slice(0, 542); //length 542
params["stack2"] = e.stackTrace.slice(1, 543); //length 542
params["stack3"] = e.stackTrace.slice(2, 544); //length 542
// Length > 1600 chars
```

The receiving party is an ASP.NET 4 site on the same domain and port.

I hope someone already came across a similar restrictions or has some general advice on how to trace this problem down further.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All I can offer is that this is unlike to be a problem with Flex, I am posting 500kb in one field on a regular basis, sometimes up to 2MB without any problem.

Comment: Can you maybe post a code snippet as solution to this thread? I might be overseeing something and your code could provide some valuable hints... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might have been a problem with the data I was sending. I am now encoding the data to **Base64** and can send large chunks of data without problems.

```
base64 = new Base64Encoder();
base64.encodeUTFBytes(text);
params['stacktrace'] = base64.flush();
```